# Summing the bytes of two files

Tags: perl

I want to take each byte of the a file and add the corresponding byte of a second file to it. I would like to output the hex of the result.

For example:

```
$ od -t x1 file1
0000000 78
0000001

$ od -t x1 file2
0000000 78
0000001

$ cat desired_output.txt
F0
```

My code currently takes each single character to sum, like in my example:

> `7` + `7` = `E`, `8` + `8` = `10`

instead of

> `78` + `78` = `F0`.

This is my code.

```
use warnings 'all';
use strict;
use autodie;

{
    my $input = do {
        open my $in, '<', $ARGV[0];
        local $/;
        <$in>
    };

    open my $out, '>', 'hex.txt';
    print $out unpack 'H*', $input;
}

{
    my $input = do {
        open my $in, '<', $ARGV[1];
        local $/;
        <$in>
    };

    open my $out, '>', 'hex2.txt';
    print $out unpack 'H*', $input;
}

open my $fh1, '<', 'hex.txt';
open my $fh2, '<', 'hex2.txt';

until ( eof $fh1 or eof $fh2 ) {

    my @l1 = map hex, split //, <$fh1>;
    my @l2 = map hex, split //, <$fh2>;

    my $n = @l2 > @l1 ? @l2 : @l1;

    my @sum = map {

        $l1[$_] + $l2[$_];
    } 0 .. $n-1;

    @sum = map { sprintf '%X', $_ } @sum;

    open my $out, '>', 'out.txt';
    print { $out } @sum, "\n";
}
```

Comment: What is the `x` for?

Comment: You've posted numerous questions and still need help since you've never been clear about what you wanted to do. Your descriptions are inadequate, and misuse words such as "hex". Help yourself by helping us by providing clearer descriptions of what you are trying to do. Specifically, please use tools such as `od` or `cat` (as appropriate) to communicate the contents of files rather than trying to describe them. Also, be sure to provided the expected output using the same method.

Comment: I've determined what you meant to ask by reverse engineering your answer, and I have updated the question to match.

Comment: @ikegami: So the OP is asking for help to make the code that he shows work properly, and you change his question to fit the code that he has written? Way to go

Comment: No, I didn't change anything.  I just rephrased "File 1:x `hex value of file 1: 78`" to make it clear his file contains one byte: `x` aka `78` hex.

Comment: @ikegami: From his history of questions, I suspect that even that isn't correct, and that he's unaware of the difference. He has variously summed character codes, hex characters (with and without a carry) hex character pairs, and hex character strings. Like you I am waiting for a real job spec

Comment: @JohnPietrar: You [said before](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34721175/read-specific-text-patterns-in-perl#comment57192737_34721473) that you had been "forced" to learn Perl in only ten days, and that you would be fine with C, C++, Java or Lisp. I wish you would follow up on my suggestion that you write a working solution in your preferred language. Most of us here know those languages and could understand from your code what you were really trying to do

Comment: @ikegami: Okay, if you're insisting on putting words into the OP's mouth, then please at least change the subject line appropriately

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a solution on my own. I used:

```
open my $fh1, '<', 'hex.txt';
open my $fh2, '<', 'hex2.txt';

until ( eof $fh1 or eof $fh2 ) {


    my @l1 = map hex,unpack '(a2)*', <$fh1>;
    my @l2 = map hex,unpack '(a2)*', <$fh2>;

    my $n = @l2 > @l1 ? @l2 : @l1;

    my @sum = map {

        $l1[$_] + $l2[$_];
    } 0 .. $n-1;

    @sum = map { sprintf '%X', $_ } @sum;

    open my $out, '>', 'sum.txt';
    print { $out } @sum, "\n";
}
```

Comment: It might be more efficient to use `unpack 'C*', pack 'H*'` instead of `map hex,unpack '(a2)*'`.

Comment: First you write comments saying that you want to add *character codes* but now you say you have found a solution that adds *hex strings*. You need to be much more careful about describing what you want to do

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that you are reading the files line by line using `split //`, which gives you each *character*, but you want two. That's not possible with `split`.

You can use [`read` to grab two bytes at a time](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/read.html) from the file. Those you can convert to *decimal* by using `hex`. I used [List::MoreUtils'](https://metacpan.org/pod/List::MoreUtils#pairwise-BLOCK-ARRAY1-ARRAY2) `pairwise` to simplify that.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use List::MoreUtils 'pairwise';
use Data::Dumper;

my @l1;
my @l2 = (78, 79, 80);
until (eof \*DATA) {
    read \*DATA, my $chars, 2;
    push @l1, $chars;
}


# sum them up
my @sums = map { sprintf '%X', $_ } pairwise {  hex($a) + hex($b) } @l1, @l2;
print Dumper \@sums;

__DATA__
787878
```

Answer (score 0):

Mapping to hex and then adding causes the behavior your are describing.  Don't do that.  Add the character values as integers first, then convert the resulting integer to a string of hex.

```
printf "%X\n", ord("x") + ord("x");
```

Looping over the input files, and assuming (as per comment) that the files are always the same length, maybe something like

```
$/ = undef;
open my $input1, '<', $ARGV[0] or die "Could not open $ARGV[0]: $!";
my $str1 = <$input1>;
close($input1);  # Don't forget to close()!
open my $input2, '<', $ARGV[1] or die "Could not open $ARGV[1]: $!";
my $str2 = <$input2>;
close($input2);
@sums = ();
for (my $i=0; $i < $#input1; ++$i) {
    push @sums, ord(substr($input1, $i, 1)) + ord(substr($input2, $i, 1));
}
```

Copying the hex representation of the input files to a separate output file for each did not seem central to your question, so is left as a (trivial) exercise.

Comment: I think the `x` is not part of the input. That was just weird formatting by OP. I tried fixing that, but forgot one. The input as far as I understand is `78`, and it reads `7` and `8` as two chars, instead of reading both at the same time.

Comment: can you show me an exact example of how to do that from files?

Comment: The question says both files contain `x` and the hex of the ASCII code for `x` is 0x78.  I think I stand by my interpretation.

Comment: Your requirements are vague.  What should the code do if the files contain lines of different length?

Comment: if you input in file1:xz file2:xz then we will have 2 output files hex1:787A , hex2:787A and instead of an output sum of the 2 hex files of "f0f4" we will have an output of "E10E14"

Comment: So if you have file1:xz and file2:xyz (different lengths of input) what should the code do?

Comment: they never have different length they are always the same length

Comment: Ok, so the `x` is in the first file **that you process to hex in a first step** and then you read that and it contains `78`.

Comment: Is writing the interim hex results to a separate file a proper requirement, or just something you put in for debugging?  Your code seems to hard-code a lot of arcane and inflexible things.

Comment: Yes, and after I sum the 2 hex files into a 3rd file

Answer (score 0):

Hex is a *text* representation of a number. To add the numbers two hex strings represent, they must first be converted to *numbers* (e.g. using [`hex`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/hex.html)).

But why are you converting to hex at all? Instead of doing *byte ⇒ hex ⇒ num*, the following does *byte ⇒ num* directly.

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';
use autodie;

my $file1 = do {
   open my $fh, '<:raw', $ARGV[0];
   local $/;
   <$fh>
};

my $file2 = do {
   open my $fh, '<:raw', $ARGV[1];
   local $/;
   <$fh>
};

my @l1 = unpack('C*', $file1);
my @l2 = unpack('C*', $file2);

my $n = @l2 > @l1 ? @l2 : @l1;
my @sums = map { $l1[$_] + $l2[$_] } 0..$n-1;

my $file_out = pack('C*', @sums);   # This is probably what you actually want in your file
print unpack('H*', $file_out);      # But this is what you said you wanted.
```