# Read specific text patterns in perl

Tags: perl

I want to read from a text file only specific text, for example:
FileExample:

```
1111111/first/second/third/fourth.c11111111...etc...
1111111/afirst/asecond/athird/afourth.c11111111...etc...etc
```

I would like to read the whole file except the part of the file from the 3rd "1" from the first "/" until the ".c" after the 4th "/" to make myself more clear I will bold the text I want my program to read and leave unbolded the part of the text I don't want my program to read.

> **1111**111/first/second/third/fourth.c**11111111...etc...etc**
>   **1111**111/afirst/asecond/athird/afourth.c**11111111...etc...etc**

after I do all the operations I want with the bolded text,I want to write it in another file the unbolded text unmodified and the bolded text with the modifications made after the operations,and placed in the original file order.

```
open my $fh1, '<', 'hex.txt';
open my $fh2, '<', 'hex2.txt';

until ( eof $fh1 or eof $fh2 ) {


    my @l1 = map hex,unpack '(a2)*', <$fh1>;
    my @l2 = map hex,unpack '(a2)*', <$fh2>;

    my $n = @l2 > @l1 ? @l2 : @l1;

    my @sum = map {

        $l1[$_] + $l2[$_];
    } 0 .. $n-1;

    @sum = map { sprintf '%X', $_ } @sum;

    open my $out, '>', 'sum.txt';
    print { $out } @sum, "\n";
}
```

I want to sum the hex values from the file hex to the sum values from file hex2,both files have the same construction type, both have text and hex values in the same location and have the exact same length.i just need to understand how to tell him to read from location1 to location2.

> Convert file to hex:

```
{
    my $input = do {
        open my $in, '<', $ARGV[0];
        local $/;
        <$in>
    };

    open my $out, '>', 'hex.txt';

    print $out unpack 'H*', $input;

}
```

Comment: I would suggest using regular expressions. What have you tried so far?

Comment: You forgot to add your code for this task.

Comment: For the patters reading part I didn't do anything because I have no idea on how it works ,I am fairly new to perl and I tried to read a lot about this part and I have no idea on how to do it...the only way I found on how to do it is by using grep but even so it doesn't help only to read from a string to another one and I don't know how to use grep in perl only in Linux...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your precise criteria aren't clear. Are those digits always ones? It's a mistake to show such a very simple example when you're hoping for help. But I suggest you use `split`

Something like this perhaps?

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

my $data = do {
    local $/;
    <DATA>;
};

$data =~ tr/\n//d;

say for split qr{\d\d\d(?:/\w+)+/\w+\.c}, $data;

__DATA__
1111111/first/second/third/fourth.c11111111...etc...
1111111/afirst/asecond/athird/afourth.c11111111...etc...etc
```

### output

```
1111
11111111...etc...1111
11111111...etc...etc
```

Answer (score 0):

I changed the input to be able to recognize what 1's it matches:

```
abcd111/first/second/third/fourth.cX1111111...etc...
abcd111/afirst/asecond/athird/afourth.cX1111111...etc...etc
```

This seems to produce the output you want

```
perl -pe 's=([^/]+).../.*\.c=$1='
```

- `[^/]` is a character class, it matches anything that's not a slash;
- `+` means it must be present one or more times
- putting it into parentheses makes it a "capture group", i.e. Perl will remember what matched that part.
- `.../` matches any three character followed by a slash.
- `.*` matches anything.
- `\.c` matches a dot followed by a `c`.
- the whole matching part (`abcd` in the sample input, up to the `c` before `X`) is substituted (hence the starting `s`) with `$1`, i.e. the contents of the first capture group, i.e. the `abcd` in the sample input.

Comment: can you help me with an easy example on how to implement this?for example if I open a file and convert all the values from the file into hex how can I tell him how to convert the specific text I want I added the conversion code above.

Comment: You changed the question. I replied to the older version.

Comment: I understand it is a reply to the older version but I don't know how to implement it ,I understand now from what you explained to me what each of the characters does but I don't understand how to you implement it because if I add perl -pe 's=([^/]+).../.*\.c=$1=' to my code I get an error about predeclaring "pe"

Comment: @JohnPietrar: If the real problem is that you simply don't know Perl then you should be looking at [learn.perl.org](http://learn.perl.org/) rather than Stack Overflow. We aren't here to churn out solutions for people who don't know their job

Comment: I was forced to learn perl in 10 days be a bit understanding, I tried to learn from learn.perl.org but some things can't be understood just by reading it, specific problems need some explaining, I learn easier from examples I wish it was c or c++ or java or lisp but no,it's perl and I rly am trying my best...

Comment: @JohnPietrar: You keep coming up repeatedly with the same problems, despite solutions being shown to you in the examples that you prefer. And regardless of the language, you don't appear to have the *requirement* clear in your head. Sometimes you are adding character codes, sometimes hex strings, sometimes truncating the overflow and sometimes carrying it. The biggest problem seems to be that you don't understand your *goal*, and if you can't how is there any possibility that we can help? I suggest you write this in C++ and get the output you need so that you have something to show us